# Сравнить 2 массива и удалить значения из 1

Tags: javascript, массивы, поиск, сравнение, фильтрация

Есть 2 массива. Как сравнить их и в массиве ups оставить только значения те значения, которые есть в массиве arr?

```js
let upd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let arr = [1, 9];
for (let el of upd) {
  if (!arr.includes(el)) {
    upd.splice(upd.indexOf(el), 1);
  }
}

console.log(upd)
```

метод splice не работает, после первого совпадения на цифре 2 порядок индексов сбиваеться

Comment: А не проще массив Arr скопировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [filter](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#filter) для фильтрации массива и методом [includes](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof-i-includes) для поиска нужных элементов

```js
let upd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let arr = [1, 9];

upd = upd.filter(i => !arr.includes(i));

console.log(upd)
```

Если массив менять нельзя(в примере выше все таки создается новый массив вместо прежднего), то можно воспользоваться методом [splice](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#splice), только обход надо делать с конца, что бы нумерация была правильной

```js
const upd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const arr = [1, 9];
for (let i = upd.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
  if (arr.includes(upd[i])) upd.splice(i,1);
}

console.log(upd)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь работает

Comment: В смысле "что бы нумерация была правильной"? Попробуйте написать обычный цикл `i = 0; i < ...; i++`, результат будет тот же.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Метод splice меняет массив на месте, поэтому если идти с начала, то после первого удаления элемента(например с индексом 2), следующие элементы поменяют индексы и тот что был условно 3-й станет вторым, в то время, как цикл уже пойдет на 3й и будет пропущен элемент.  Под нумерацией, имелось ввиду индексы массива.